# How to control constraint over multi devices in iOS/Storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I've been working on a project that supports multiple screen sizes for iOS. Thanks to Storyboard and auto layout technology, I could be able to handle some constraint automatically based on device screen size. But in some cases, I couldn't figure out how to deal with auto constraint when I apply constant constraint in Storyboard. For example, lets say I put a button in view controller on Storyboard and set constraints (Tailing/Leading space as 44 and Top space as 50). This button surely expand its width based on device screen size but I also want to change top space proportional to its screen size. Assume base top space 50 is set for iPhone 4 screen size (320/480), then I would like to increase it as device screen height increases. The way I manage this for now is, check screen size and change its constraint constant respectively which is 50 * (568/480) (i.e. I want to keep same ratio). I wonder if there is a way to do this trick on storyboard. I would appreciate any advices.

Comment: yes you can give that constraint like equal or greater than 40 but make sure to change other constraints  acc to ur need.

Comment: if I set that constraint equal or greater than 40, then would it be automatically changed based on screen height?